# Swift4 Image View

Tags: swift, xcode

When I try to hide an image out of many images in my project by using imageView.isHidden = true,  all images are hidden(and on using imageViewHidden.isHidden = false the image does not come back) instead of one that I desire as imageView is a Collective object for the class UIImageView.

Please let me know how can we hide the specific image from two or more images in the Project.

I know it can be done by using the object used for the particular image but I have two classes

Comment: Please explain more and make sure that both image View are not connected to same IBoutlet

Comment: please explain and provide code

Comment: I have created image Views programmatically and on click of the button a table view pops up and when the table view is visible (a boolean has been created for the button which becomes true on the first click and then on the following click turns false and so on). I want at that time(when table view is open or when boolean is true) the image View to be visible and on click of the same button when the boolean value changes from true to false I want the image to be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide an imageView use either the same outlet that is referring to the same imageView 
(for eg. imageView1.isHidden = true)

or use tag value to hide an imageView on the same ViewController by

```
if let imageView1 = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UIImageView {
      imageView1.isHidden = true
}
```

And if you want to unhide the same image view, write the code

```
imageView1.isHidden = false
```

Make sure you are using the same imageView outlet, you want to show or hide.